# pointer times variable value, var = (var + 1)&3

Tags: c, pointers

The code I am referring to occurs 
[here](https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/eaf6ab250df63652cd455f0c051ce7e03f4f641b/Ghidra/Features/Decompiler/src/decompile/cpp/xml.y#L79). I did not know that this was legal c that does not result in a segfault. what does it mean? is it equivalent to `var = &var[3]`?

Comment: There are no pointers here, `pos` is an `int4` (probably a typedef for `int32_t` or the like).  It just adds 1 to `var`, ands the result with `3` (effectively finding the remainder mod 4), and stores the result back in `var`.  What else did you think it did?

Comment: The `pos` variable is an integer declared as `int4`, not a pointer. Why would you expect a segfault due to arithmetic operation on integers?

Comment: Perhaps you are mixing up the unary operator `&` (address-of) with the binary operator `&` (bitwise and)?  If it were the unary `&` the expression would not be valid; there's no meaning in C for two expressions next to one another (in particular it's not multiplication).

Comment: Why do you modify the question to make it inconsistent with the code you're refering to?

Comment: Post the relevant code here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. The expression `pos = (pos+1)&3;` is equivalent to

```
pos = pos + 1;
pos = pos & 3;
```

except it does not imply storing the intermediate value back to the `pos` variable.

**EDIT** to reply the additional question in a comment

The bitwise AND operator truncates, or rather wraps, the incrementing process at the value of 3. The code could be written as

```
pos = pos + 1;
pos = pos % 4;
```

which in this context means:

```
pos = pos + 1;
if( pos > 3 )
    pos = 0;
```

However, the arithmetic <del>modulus</del> modulo (thanks, @chux - Reinstate Monica) or the bitwise AND expressions make the same result in fewer operations, most important without a conditional branch, which would downgrade the efficiency.

Compare the question [Why is processing a sorted array faster than processing an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/733637) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/733637) to it.

Comment: Ah I was being a dummy, Read the ```&``` and immediately thought ```pointer```. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know why a position variable would be logical AND'd with 3?

Comment: Nvm here it is so that ```pos``` never reaches 4 as ```4 = 0100``` and ```pos``` sets the value of ```lookahead[4]```. Taking the AND ensures that pos never reaches out-of-bounds in ```lookahead```

Comment: Wrong. Integer constants starting with `0` are considered _octal_ in C, so `0100` is `64`, not `4`.

Comment: `pos = pos % 4;` differs from `pos = pos & 3;` when `pos < 0`. I see no initialization of `pos` preventing `pos < 0` unless it is buried in the C++ `int4`. `%` is a remainder operator, not a Euclidean modulus.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Nothing is 'buried in C++' here, it is explicitly written in the code. See the `XmlScan` constructor for initialization of `pos` to zero.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right, I meant 'modulo' but typed too fast and didn't check before submitting.

Comment: Er - I meant `modulo` too.  `%` is a remainder operator, not a Euclidean modulo.  Results differ with `a%b` when `a < 0` - which appenly does not apply in _this_ code.

Comment: @CiaPan I'm confused how you are getting octal from ```int4 pos = 0```?  0 would be interpreted as an integer...

Comment: I think you meant if ```0100``` were in the src code because then you would have an octal number. But I was referring to the byte representation.

Comment: @skyfire You wrote `4 = 0100`. It's clear to me you meant a binary representation here, but you didn't say that. And when we talk about the program in C/C++ we should comply to C/C++ syntax – and it defines a constant starting with digit `0` as octal (see e.g. [_C - Constants and Literals_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_constants.htm) at TutorialsPoin.com), hence `0100` is 8 squared, i.e. `64` in decimal.